# Code Blocks error when using while(scanf) in C

Tags: c, compiler-errors, runtime-error, codeblocks

I have attached a piece of code below which works perfectly fine in an online compiler but fails to work in Code Blocks compiler when using C. I have attached screenshots as well.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    int array[100];
    while(scanf("%d",&array[i])>0)
    {
        i++;
    }
    for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
    {
        printf("%d ",array[j]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Using Online compiler(GeeksForGeeks)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whHe3.png)

[Using CODEBLOCKS compiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L38v6.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no error, your `while` loop will go on until an invalid input is entered, you have no limit for the number of inputs so it will continue taking values, which may later become a problem since your container only has space for 100 `int`s.

It stops on some online compilers because of the way they use `stdin` inputs, it's basically a one time readout.

**Examples:**

It stops [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/DBLlFdzl1kL42B7I), has one time `stdin` readout.

It doesn't stop [here](https://onlinegdb.com/SJQgPQ8TU), has a console like input/output.

So if you want to stop at a given number of inputs you can do something like:

```
//...
while (i < 5 && scanf(" %d", &array[i]) > 0)
{
    i++;
}
//...
```

This will read 5 `int`s, exit the loop and continue to the next statement.

If you don't really know the number of inputs, you can do something like:

```
//...
while (i < 100 && scanf("%d", &array[i]) > 0) { // still need to limit the input to the
                                                // size of the container, in this case 100
    i++;
    if (getchar() == '\n') { // if the character is a newline break te cycle  
                             // note that there cannot be spaces after the last number
        break;
    }
}
//...
```

The previous version lacks some error checks so for a more comprehensive approach you can do somenthing like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> // strcspn
#include <stdlib.h> // strtol
#include <errno.h>  // errno
#include <limits.h> // INT_MAX

int main() {

    char buf[1200]; // to hold the max number of ints
    int array[100];
    char *ptr; // to iterate through the string
    char *endptr; // for strtol, points to the next char after parsed value
    long temp; //to hold temporarily the parsed value
    int i = 0;

    if (!fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin)) { //check input errors

        fprintf(stderr, "Input error");
    }

    ptr = buf; // assing pointer to the beginning of the char array

    while (i < 100 && (temp = strtol(ptr, &endptr, 10)) && temp <= INT_MAX 
    && errno != ERANGE && (*endptr == ' ' || *endptr == '\n')) {

        array[i++] = temp; //if value passes checks add to array
        ptr += strcspn(ptr, " ") + 1; // jump to next number
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) { //print the array

        printf("%d ", array[j]);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Then how I am supposed to get an array without knowing the size of the array in Code Blocks?

Comment: @HaamithSulthan, you mean you don't know how many values are inputed by the user?

Comment: Yes, that was the problem faced by me.

Comment: @HaamithSulthan I added 2 solutions to the answer, one more simple and another more comprehensive.